# Undo content in vim

Tags: vim

How can I do undo in vim? Can I have shortcut for this? 
Suppose I delete some text or change and I want to reload those changes. Mostly I am doing ESCAPE and :q!, but this is very long way.

Comment: Btw: vim comes with a very smart, interactive tutorial. Just call "vimtutor" from your CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need to do following steps

1. hit on ESCAPE key
2. and hit on "u" key (small caps) (NO NEED TO CHOOSE : after hitting on ESCAPE)

I hope this will help, if you do little Google or stackoverflow, tons of same type of questions availables.

Comment: This solutions works for me. It is very simple to understand. Thanks amit

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>u</kbd> key (in command mode) undoes any editing function.

Note that if you have `compatible` mode set, then <kbd>u</kbd> performs only the function in vi, that is only one level of undo (a second <kbd>u</kbd> would undo the undo, that is, a redo). In `nocompatible` mode, the undo level is multi-level and goes back all the way until the point where you loaded the file (<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> is the redo command).

Make sure you have a `~/.vimrc` file to turn off `compatible` mode.

Comment: Statement “goes back all the way until the point where you loaded the file” is false: it goes back until reaches last recorded state (which may be state when you first loaded the file in this vim session, in all vim sessions (if persistent undo is on) or state that is 'undolevels' far from current).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options (from command mode):

`u` will undo an editing action.

`U` will undo all edits to a line

`:earlier` will let you undo a number of actions or take you back to how the text looked seconds, minutes and so forth ago. See [here for a list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#%3aearlier).

Answer (score 0):

I like "ESCAPE:u" (for "undo") :)

Here's a good cheat sheet:

- http://bullium.com/support/vim.html

PS:

ESCAPE :e! MYFILE is a good way to abort editing and reload the file ... without exiting or re-entering "vi".

Answer (score 0):

In Command mode (after hitting escape), just hit `u`.

Answer (score 0):

u is undo
Ctrl +r is redo
hope this helps

You can check all other commands here
http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html